# How to remove extra space between textfield in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created three text field in Header. I have put parameter in all `textField` elements. When I'm not calling one of three parameter of three `textField` elements. It will show 2 `textField` elements. The problem now is there are space between the text fields.

How to remove the space?

This is my code:

```xml
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="0" y="18" width="555" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
        <font size="12"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{daterangefrom}  && $P{daterangeto}  ?  "From ( " + $P{daterangefrom} + " - " + $P{daterangeto} + ")"
: $P{weeks}  && $P{monthy} && $P{yrs} ? "For week " + $P{weeks} +" "+ $P{monthy} +" "+ $P{yrs}
: $P{monthy}  && $P{yrs} ? "For monthly " +$P{monthy} +" "+ $P{yrs}
: $P{quarter}  &&  $P{yrs}  ? "For Quarter " + $P{quarter} +" "+$P{yrs}
: $P{yrs}  ? "For " + $P{yrs}
: null]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

This is mine result:

[image]

Comment: You can use one `textField`. What kind of fields placement are you using (vertically or horizontally)?

Comment: im use vertical.yesterday, i'm using combine all in one textfield and i put double line. when one of three not show. it will show 2 textfield. but there are space in textfield. how to remove the space so that report can display a more structured?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use 3 *`textField`* elements with ***`isRemoveLineWhenBlank`*** property set to `true` value.

The sample (jrxml file):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport .. topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <parameter name="parameter1" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="parameter2" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="parameter3" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="102" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="163" y="9" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{parameter1} == null ? null : "Parameter1: " + $P{parameter1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="163" y="29" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{parameter2} == null ? null : "Parameter2: " + $P{parameter2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="163" y="49" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{parameter3} == null ? null : "Parameter3: " + $P{parameter3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="163" y="73" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Static text]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="63" y="6" width="447" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="73" y="96" width="447" height="1"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The report design in `iReport`:
[image: Report's design in iReport]

For the *parameter1=null, parameter2=null, parameter1=value3* the result will be:
[image: The result in iReport (preview mode)]

***UPDATE***

For solving the problem of moving up the *`textField`* in case the element above was hide you can use the *`Frame`* container. You should add 2 frames (one per column) and put 2 *`textField`* elements (2 rows) in each frame.

The sample (jrxml file):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport .. topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <parameter name="par1" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="par2" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="par3" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="par4" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[null]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="80" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="10" y="6" width="520" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="10" y="72" width="520" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="329" y="10" width="172" height="59"/>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="13" y="3" width="60" height="54"/>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="1" y="20" width="52" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{par3} == null ? null : "P3: " + $P{par3}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="52" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{par1} == null ? null : "P1: " + $P{par1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="73" y="3" width="70" height="54"/>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="52" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{par2} == null ? null : "P2: " + $P{par2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="1" y="20" width="52" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{par4} == null ? null : "P4: " + $P{par4}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
            </frame>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="10" y="30" width="52" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{par3} == null ? null : "P3: " + $P{par3}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="10" y="10" width="52" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{par1} == null ? null : "P1: " + $P{par1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="64" y="10" width="52" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{par2} == null ? null : "P2: " + $P{par2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="64" y="30" width="52" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{par4} == null ? null : "P4: " + $P{par4}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The report design in `iReport`:
[image: The design in iReport. Two cases]

For the *par1=null, par2=2, par3=3, par4=4* the result will be: 
[image: The result in iReport preview. Two cases]

You can compare the results - left side is done without using `frame` and the right side with *`frame`* elements.

Comment: @Amin Just added the report's design screenshot

Comment: Thank you @Alex k. but i have one more question,how about if I put total 4 TextField. i put 2 textfield at line 1 and 2 textfield at line 2. how to remove the space if remove one textfield in line 1?.

Comment: For example you have `txtFieldName1` and `txtFieldValue1` at first row and `txtFieldName2` and `txtFieldValue2` at second row (line). If the expression of `txtFieldName1` element is null, do you want to hide both elements (`txtFieldName1` and `txtFieldValue1`) and show only one row (with `txtFieldName2` and `txtFieldValue2` elements) in this case or do you want to show `txtFieldName2` and `txtFieldValue1` at first row and only `txtFieldValue2` at second row? Can you explain me the rule?

Comment: i'm sorry late to reply,i have show the rule in my pictures.This is my picture.[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PpOkq.jpg.Hope you can help me.

Comment: @Amin I've just add sample for your second case

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to fix problems like this, but unless you provide more detailed information about your report. I can't really come up some good suggestions.

But here are few tips might help you.

**Use one `TextField` and one parameter.**

Instead of composing your header in jrxml with separate `TextField`, you can compose it in `Java` first, then store as the parameter. This way you can make `Java` help you with all the logic about composing the string.

**Use one `TextField` and three parameters**

You can simply write expressions like this in the `TextField`

```
$P{FirstName} + " " + ${MiddleName} + " " + ${LastName}
```

so you can prevent the gap that caused by empty `TextField`. Or use shorthand condition expression like this.

```
$P{FirstName} + (${MiddleName}.isEmpty() ? "" : " " + ${MiddleName}) + " " + ${LastName}
```

Comment: Can you update your code into your question ? comment is not a good place to read code. And please **explain your problem**, like what result you expect your report looks like, but how it looks now.

Comment: i have put my code and i change report to javascript,this is my pictures, http://i.stack.imgur.com/guooK.jpg

Comment: We tried with this example its working fine for me.how we can implement the same with "fields" instead of  "Param"