# iReport dynamic parameter passing or triming space between two row

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove extra space between textfield in JasperReports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071943/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-textfield-in-jasperreports)

i Need to remove empty parameter row from ireport or java.

i have added print when condition for each parameter for checking null value.

if null value come the parameter label and value should not get displayed.

but it display blank line instead of parameter.how to trim this.chek below image for same.

[image]

need to remove entire row between two line.circled as below.

[image]

I am simply passing value to it's related parameter.all parameter already been defined in ireport and i will set value using java code like below

```
parameters.put("EQUI_YIELD_LABEL",basePropertyForm.getPmlEquivYieldPercLabelValue());
parameters.put("EQUI_YIELD",pmlPropertyMasterLk.getPmlEquivYieldPerc());
```

how to do same ?

Please suggest..

Comment: @Juraj Polak's idea is probably what's needed. Alex K's link covers the same thing in more detail including samples.

Comment: I have two different textfield i na single row.how to deal with it ?