# How to remove blank spaces when report element is not printed?

Tags: jasper-reports

PDF generated using jasper, is having blank spaced when report element is not printed(Used printWhenExpression).
I tried to set removeBlankSpace property but This also didn’t work resolve issue at all places.

Please help me if there is any solution. I will try.

Comment: You should post the screenshot of your report's design (in *iReport*) and *jrxml* file

Comment: You can try to use different values of ***Position Type*** property. May be the **Fix Relative to Top** value will be the best in your case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove extra space between textfield in JasperReports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071943/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-textfield-in-jasperreports)