# How to remove blank space between textfields in iReport Designer

Tags: jasper-reports, textfield

I use iReport Designer 5.6.0. I have the same problem as described here- [How to remove extra space between textfield in JasperReports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071943/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-textfield-in-jasperreports)

I want avoid an extra space between text fields and parameters in Designer, below didn't work out for me:

1. I set the position property for all the fields to float.
2. I checked the property checkbox by the name remove line when blank.
3. I checked the property checkbox by the name blank when null (to remove null values from the report).

How can I shrink/remove blank space between textfield?

Comment: could you give me an example (screenshot preferably)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot do it, because I don't have enough points for attaching it.

Comment: You can take a screenshot, upload it to imgur.com or any image host, and put the link in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try trim function to solve your problem.
```

`$F{name}.trim()
    $P{add}.trim()`

`trim` function eliminates leading and trailing blanks. it may solve.

Answer (score 0):

As far i know, there is no option for this on horizontal lines.

What are the values of this text fields.
If they are fields, parameters or variables you can just add one text field and create an expression that checks on empty values. The expression is something like this:

```
$P{param1} + 
(!$P{param2}.isEmpty() ? " " + $P{param2} : "") +
(!$P{param3}.isEmpty() ? " " + $P{param3} : "")
```

of course this only works when you are using fields, parameters and variables