# How to remove blank table rows In iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm searching for a while now and everything that I tried doesn't work. I'm using iReport to design a custom report and I'm not able to remove blank rows in my table.

Indeed, sometimes I have some null values on the entire row so I've checked the "BlankWhenNull" box in iReport. But to avoid blank spaces I've also checked the "RemoveBlankLine" box and set my textfield positions to float but it doesn't work for me.

Here's a screenchot of what I get and what I would :
I know that the fields are not correctly in the columns but it actually doesn't matter, I'm just testing.

Here's what I get:
[image: Here's what I get]
As you can see there is some white space due to lines removed

Here's what I would:
[image: Here's what I would]
And here there is no white spaces as I would

I'm using table component as subreport and it seems to be a very different use.

Here is the JRXML file : http://pastebin.com/7tBQU3MD

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4875631/frankerz).

Comment: @greg Possible duplicate: [How to remove extra space between textfield in JasperReports?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10071943/876298)

Comment: show jrxml code, i check it

Comment: @Alex K Thanks but I read it and I'm not able to resolve my problem because I'm using table component and it seems to be a very different use

Comment: @Abihabi87 Thank you, it's pretty long so I used pastebin
http://pastebin.com/7tBQU3MD
Edit : I drew my grid in the detail band and I read that I should rather use background band so don't pay attention to my lines in detail band;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
isStretchWithOverflow="true" 
isBlankWhenNull="true"
isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"
```

Comment: Hi Abihabi87; your code-answer might be useful, but it would be better with some context; for example, you could explain how and why these proposed changes would resolve the questioner's problem. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: @Abihabi87 Thank for your answer but I already done it and it doesn't work. Let me explain a little more my report structure. I have a report with EmptyDataSource and inside this report I have a table filled with a JTableModelDataSource directly from my java program. Each columns of my table contains a TextField with parameters like $F{COLUMN_0} ... etc
All of my fields have the parameters 
isStretchWithOverflow="true" 
isBlankWhenNull="true"
isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"
And even the table itself but I don't understand why it's not working.