# Remove Line When Blank not working for Relative to Band height stretch type

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report with position type float for all elements and stretch type Relative to Band Height and no stretch for different element. For one particular case I want my textField to completely vanish depending upon Print when expression, so I have Remove Line When Blank checked. But the problem is, there is small gap between element above and below it when it is gone.

This is what I expect.

[image]

This is what I get

[image]

Following is my textField

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="617" width="278" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#00FFFF" uuid="b8a09e5a-b3ff-4ddf-b833-3cf854f1108e">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{SOME_VALUE}!=null)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="4" isBold="true" isItalic="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold"/>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="1" rightIndent="1"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SOME_VALUE}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

If the stretch type is No stretch it works as expected and no gap between elements, but it is not working for Relative to Band Height. How do I solve this issue?

**EDIT**

I tried keeping elements inside the frame but result is the same (Like I have said, it works when stretch type is No Stretch, but there is gap for Relative to Band Height).

**LAST EDIT**

I had to keep the Middle dynamic element on it's own band to make that work.My detail band was really complicated and there were other dynamic elements which might have resulted on growth of space on the band.

Comment: Try making the `positionType` to `Fixed Relative to Top` for the `Element Below`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove extra space between textfield in JasperReports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071943/how-to-remove-extra-space-between-textfield-in-jasperreports)

Comment: @Viki888 I cannot use that because I need elements to float because there are other dynamic fields that have variable heights.